# Error :"Cannot subscript a value of type'[String: Array<String>]' with an index of type 'Int'"

Tags: xcode, swift

Assignment: "Create an application that displays a list of gas stations and their gas prices and distance. Store the information into a Dictionary.  Display the results in a table view. Let the user select an entry and then display a UIAlert dialog showing the entry."

I am working on the dictionary part. The code for the dictionary is

```
"var gasStation = ["76": ["$2.76", "1.2 miles"],
                   "Arco":["$2.56", "2.4 miles"],
                   "Shell":["$3.54", "3.5 miles"],
                   "Tower mart": ["$2.36", "5.7 miles"]]"
```

The error pops up on this line of code

```
cell!.textLabel!.text = gasStation[indexPath.row]
```

Here is the New Updated code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,     UITableViewDelegate {

let dwarves = [ "Sleepy", "Sneezy", "bashful", "Happy"]

let gasStation = ["76": ["$2.76", "1.2 miles"],
    "Arco":["$2.56", "2.4 miles"],
    "Shell":["$3.54", "3.5 miles"],
    "Tower-Mart": ["$2.36", "5.7 miles"]]

   var gasStationNames = Array(gasStation) // error: "ViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'gasStation'

let simpleTableIdentifier = "SimpleTableIdentifier"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dwarves.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
        simpleTableIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell

        if (cell == nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(
        style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: simpleTableIdentifier)
    }
    cell!.textLabel?.text = dwarves[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
}

}
```

Comment: gasStation it is a dictionary. You need to pass a key not an index. It will return an array of strings which you can access using an index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you get an array of all the gas Station names.

```
let gasStationNames = Array(gasStation.keys)
```

But it will not be in the same order.
And for assigning it to the tableView:

```
cell!.textLabel!.text = gasStationNames[indexPath.row]
```

Here, you can index `gasStationNames` with `indexPath.row` of type `Int` as it is of type `Array`. And to get a value out of Dictionary, you should pass a key of proper type.

You should have a look at this [document page](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)

**EDIT**
Assign `gasStationNames` in your `cellForRow`

```
let gasStationNames = Array(gasStation.keys)
```

and then assign to cell's textLabel

```
cell!.textLabel!.text = gasStationNames[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Thanks, but now i am getting this error "ViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'gasStation'" on the line  "let gasStationNames = Array(gasStation.keys).

Comment: Have you declared the variable 'gasStation'

Comment: Yes as per the original code i posted.       "var gasStation = ["76": ["$2.76", "1.2 miles"],
                   "Arco":["$2.56", "2.4 miles"],
                   "Shell":["$3.54", "3.5 miles"],
                   "Tower mart": ["$2.36", "5.7 miles"]]"

Comment: I have been trying to solve the issue. I have been reading that it's giving me that error because it's not in the viewDidLoad(). It works when i put the declaration in there. Then another issue arises, obviously it's out of scope now... I tried to declare the dictionary above the viewDidLoad(). Then fill it with data in the viewDidLoad(). That doesn't help either.

Comment: Post the whole controller somewhere

Comment: I started over, it was pretty messy. I am using a template of a "dwarf" table view I did. I plan to change out the dwarves variables. But here is the entire code. I updated the original post with all the code. Thanks for your help